# SSAS Calculated Measure, or Dynamic Set? Average using all

Tags: sql-server, ssas, average

My fact table contains **sparse data** and has 3 columns: (user, movie, **normalized_score**). Example:

```
  ('u1', 'm3', 0.3)
  ('u1', 'm4', 0.1)
  ('u1', 'm7', 0.6)
  ('u2', 'm1', 0.33)
  ('u2', 'm3', 0.33)
  ('u2', 'm7', 0.33)
  ('u3', 'm2', 0.6)
  ('u3', 'm6', 0.4)
  ...
```

As you can see, sum(normalized_score)=1 for each user.

I have two dimensions: 
-  `User_info (user, Cat_Level1, Cat_Level2)`  
- `Movie_info (movie, Genre_Level1, Genre_Level2)`

I want top movies by the *average* score, where calculation of average considers all the associated users from the selected dimension.

For example, at the lowest level, `average('m3')` above would be `(0.3+0.3)/3`. Note that the denominator is **3**, not 2.

Basically, any dimension we select, there's the corresponding #of users, that becomes the denominator.

Can't figure it out how. Please help!

Comment: `[Measures].[normalized_score]/[Measures].[Number of Users]`, where `[Measures].[normalized_score]` is additive and `[Measures].[Number of Users]` is a count. This is clearly not right, since the denominator is the #of users who had the movie in their records.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer was found by asking on the MSDN forums [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlanalysisservices/thread/5b1a3d0f-a805-41a7-8d5a-ea3be720af75).

> This is one of the tricky points of MDX. You really want the
>   denominator to be the count of users using the current context of
>   everything but the currently selected movie. Is your
>   [Measures].[Number of Users] metric is a DistinctCount of users? I'm
>   going to assume so to keep the discussion clearer. If the current
>   context of the movie hierarchy is m3, you would get a denominator
>   value of 2 as you stated in your initial post. To get the value of
>   three that you wish, you would need to overwrite the current movie
>   hierarchy context so that the definition of your average score would
>   be [Measures].[Normalized_Score] / ( **[Movie].[Movie].[All]**,
>   [Measures].[Number of Users] ). Change the definition of the
>   **[Movie].[Movie].[All]** to be appropriate for your cube and you should
>   get the correct denominator value

.